# Performance testing - 200 Concurrent Users Test in Jmeter is failing with 8 Machines

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have tried running a test with 150 users & 6 machines in jmeter and it ran fine with no errors. But when i increased the number of users & number of machines to 200 users and 8 machines respectively, it started throwing "java.net.socketexception: connection reset" error

Previously i was facing this error when i tried running for 150 users with 4 machines. But, after increasing the machines by 2, the 150 user test was successful. Need help in this.

I tried accessing the application manually during the execution and i was able to access the application normally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you're talking about 150 and 200 users? I'm asking because you mentioned that you tried "150 users with 4 machines" which doesn't give whole number of users if the load is split.

- 150 users and 6 machines give you 900 users in total
- 200 users and 8 machines give you 1800 users in total

1. So if you really want "200 users with 8 machines" make sure to have 25 users in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) as each JMeter slave is executing the same test plan independently so if you have 25 users in thread group and 1 slave - it will be 25 users, 2 slaves - 50 users, 3 slaves - 75 users, etc.
2. Make sure that your application is not overloaded and has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network sockets, etc. It be done with [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
3. Check your application logs as it might indicate the problem on the application side. If you're absolutely sure that application behaves correctly you might want to apply instructions from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page

Comment: Hi dmitri. Thanks for your answer. Its a total of "200 users" over 8 different machines i.e, 25 in Each machine. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 6 machines to run 200 Users ?
1 single machine should be good enough to handle smoothly such test.

Are you using a protocol (3rd party plugin) that explains this ?

Did you try running the test on your machine and see how CPU and memory were behaving before switching to distributed testing ?

Check this [blog](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/) to ensure you're using best-practices.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The configuration is Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @2.60 GHz 2.60 GHz (2 processors) RAM - 5.00 GB. 64-Operating System